# pip install ROOT Python 3 Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, anaconda, root-framework

I have Python 3, Windows 10 and want to have the CERN package ROOT.
What I tried so far based on other quests:

- as admin on anaconda prompt pip install ROOT gives:

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ROOT (from versions: none)
- on cmd with python3 -m pip install :
  does nothing

Any suggestions what requirements are missing?

Comment: Did you see [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838881/pip-install-root-python-3-windows#comment107723673_60839203) which contains a link to the package for Conda? Be careful when using pip with Conda, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Comment: thanks, thats good to know, but i have windows and could not install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `pip install` ROOT, as it doesn't appear to have an entry in pypi, nor is it supported for python 3.x. The community-supported [`rootpy`](https://pypi.org/project/rootpy/) can be pip-installed, and does have python3.x support, but it doesn't appear to be supported for Windows, so I'll add some notes below.

Per their [documentation for building ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/building-root), you can leverage Visual Studio's `cmake` for this:

> **Visual Studio**
>
> Generate the Microsoft Visual Studio solution with `cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" /path/to/source/dir`. Open the generated solution with `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe ROOT.sln`

Otherwise, they have instructions listed for vanilla `cmake` that are contained within the link above.

Note to check their [supported platforms](https://root.cern.ch/supported-platforms), which point to the following for ROOT 5:

- win32 for Win32 with Visual Studio >= 2008 / vc >= 9
- win32gcc for Win32 with cygwin/gcc with gcc >= 4.8
- win64gcc for Win64 with cygwin/gcc with gcc >= 4.8

And their [prerequisites for Windows](https://root.cern.ch/build-prerequisites#windows). ROOT 5 appears to support python 2.7, I have not seen anything indicating python3 support, at least at the time of this writing

They do have support for an alpha version of ROOT on [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/rootproject/root-ubuntu16/), which could provide a different avenue for running the ROOT package

Comment: thanks, when i try to install rootpy i get ' ROOT cannot be imported. Is ROOT installed with PyROOT enabled?'. Is this just saying thats its not supported, or may i can get it, if latter, do you have a idea how?

Comment: Then it may still require an underlying ROOT install

Comment: ok thus i have to wait till python3 is supported or use python 2.7 and Visual studios or use another OS and rootpy, thanks

Comment: ftr instead of pypi, there is a maintained conda-forge package for installing root with python 3 https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/root (though only lists linux and macos, not windows)